# Reset Counter to Zero in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, counter

I have the following code:

```
for(int sentenceCounter = 0; sentenceCounter < sentences.length; sentenceCounter++)
{
    double score = 0;
    String[] sentence = sentences[sentenceCounter].split(" ");

    for (int titleCounter = 0; titleCounter < titles.length; titleCounter++)
    {

        for (int wordCounter = 0; wordCounter < sentence.length; wordCounter++)
        {
            if (titles[titleCounter].equals(sentence[wordCounter]))
            {
                if(titleCounter == 0)
                {

                    score += titleValue * hundred / 100;
                    sentenceScore.put(sentenceCounter, score);
                    System.out.println(sentenceCounter + " " + wordCounter + " " + score);

                }else
                {

                    score +=  titleValue - titleSubtract * hundred / 100;
                    sentenceScore.put(sentenceCounter, score);
                    System.out.println(sentenceCounter + " " + wordCounter + " " + sentenceScore.get(0));
                }

                System.out.println(sentenceCounter);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to reset the score counter after the sentenceCounter increases, however when I set score = 0 at the right after the for loop of sentenceCounter it does not reset itself. So, how do I reset it?

The steps of the program is as follows: 1. Break title into single words. 2. Break sentence into single words. 3. See if sentence contains word from title. If yes then increase score of sentence by X. 4. Repeat for next word in title. 5. If sentence contains another word from title add to previous score. 6. Repeat this for next sentence but first set score counter to zero. This is where I am stuck.

This is the output I am observing from above code:

```
0 0 10.0
0
0 1 19.3
0
1 5 19.3
1
```

As you can see sentence two starts at 19.3 instead of starting at zero.

Here is the program in full:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
```

import java.util.Map;

public class MainDemo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String fullTitle = "Facebook traffic website";
    String[] titles = fullTitle.split(" ");
    Double titleValue = 10.0;
    Double sentenceSubtract = 13.0;
    Double titleSubtract = 0.70;
    Double hundred = 100.0;
    HashMap<Integer, String> titleArray = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
     for(int i =0; i < titles.length; i++)
     {
         String t = titles[i];
         titleArray.put(i, t);
     }
    String article = "Facebook traffic is growing fast. It is the second largest website. ";

    HashMap<Integer, Double> sentenceScore = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();


    String[] sentences = article.split("\\. ");
    String[] str;



    for(int sentenceCounter = 0; sentenceCounter < sentences.length; sentenceCounter++)
    {
        double score = 0;
        String[] sentence = sentences[sentenceCounter].split(" ");

        for (int titleCounter = 0; titleCounter < titles.length; titleCounter++)
        {



            for (int wordCounter = 0; wordCounter < sentence.length; wordCounter++)
            {
                if (titles[titleCounter].equals(sentence[wordCounter]))
                {
                    if(titleCounter == 0)
                    {

                        score += titleValue * hundred / 100;
                        sentenceScore.put(sentenceCounter, score);
                        System.out.println(sentenceCounter + " " + wordCounter + " " + score);

                    }else
                    {

                        score +=  titleValue - titleSubtract * hundred / 100;
                        sentenceScore.put(sentenceCounter, score);
                        System.out.println(sentenceCounter + " " + wordCounter + " " + sentenceScore.get(0));
                    }

                    System.out.println(sentenceCounter);

                }

            }
        }
    }





        }















}
```

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? What are you observing? It would really help us if you could provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem...

Comment: @JonSkeet me to couldn't understand what he means. THere is no increment in sentenceCounter

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I am testing if a keyword from title is found in sentence then increasing score of sentence if found. I keep track of the score of every sentence with sentenceScore. When we move onto next sentence I want to reset the score of "score" to zero so that it doesn't add from the score of last sentence to current sentence.

Comment: Well yes, you *are* setting the score to 0. You haven't told us what you're observing, nor have you provided us with a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: If you put a break point after the line where you reset score, and step through the program you can see how/why score changes in the way it does.

Comment: @Jon the steps of the program is as follows: 1. Break title into single words. 2. Break sentence into single words. 3. See if sentence contains word from title. If yes then increase score of sentence by X. 4. Repeat for next word in title. 5. If sentence contains another word from title add to previous score. 6. Repeat this for next sentence but first set score counter to zero. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: Where do you set/change titleValue? That could be where your problem is.

Comment: @BarneySmith: You *still* haven't told us what you've observed, and you *still* don't have a short but complete program we can run. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @BarneySmith: You are probably observing score while still within the loop. score is reinitialized to 0 at the beginning of every iteration of your outer loop.

Comment: @JonSkeet I edited the question to include output

Comment: Well that doesn't show it now being reset... There are far too many things which we can't see (the various values involved). Again, if we could reproduce the problem - due to you posting a short but complete program - then we could check what's happening.

Comment: @BarneySmith: Are you sure the printed output for the 2nd sentence is not printing from the else block? If so, than it is correct. It is printing sentenceScore.get(0) which would be the same from the previous print.. correct?

Comment: I've updated the code, sorry previous code was not copied correctly.

Comment: Right, thanks. In future, when you ask a question, please add all the relevant details right from the start - and take some time to format your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your score counter is being reset every iteration. The problem is that you are printing a different set of values if titleCounter != 0. The print to console that you are expecting to print score, is actually defined to print `sentenceScore.get(0)`.

This is correct. sentenceScore.get(0) would be the score value from last iteration before it was reset to 0.

Comment: I think you understand the problem. However, I don't understand if score is being reset to zero when sentenceCounter increments why is previous score stored in score of second sentence?

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. It's not actually being stored in score of second sentence I am just outputting the score of first sentence again in the output statement. Thanks :)

Comment: upvoted question because more details were added after the downvote was cast.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to reset a field you define in the body of the loop to zero, it will be re-created on the next iteration already -

```
for(int sentenceCounter = 0; sentenceCounter < sentences.length; sentenceCounter++)
{
  double score = 0; // <-- create a score variable, set it to 0.
  System.out.println("Score is " + score);
```

Comment: When I use this code it does not reset. Suppose sentence 1 has a score of 20, sentence two will have a score of 20 + whatever sentence two's score is. It will not reset the score to zero.

Comment: @BarneySmith Edited to add a println after initializing score to 0. The above will *always* print *Score is 0.0* because it's a double.

Comment: It does reset, if its changing back to 20, then this line is the culprit

score +=  titleValue - titleSubtract * hundred / 100;