# Resetting Counter Java

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class VowelsAndConsonants {
public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int ConsonantCount = 0;
    int VowelCount = 0;
    int num = 0;
    int x = 0;
    while(true) {
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        String userInput = input.next();
        num = userInput.length();
        for(x = 0; x < num ; x++) {
            char c = userInput.charAt(x);
            if (Character.isLetter(c)){
                c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
                if (c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'I' || c == 'O' || c == 'U') 
                    VowelCount++;
                else 
                    ConsonantCount++;


            }


        }
        System.out.println("The number of vowels is: " + VowelCount);
        System.out.println("The number of consonants is: " + ConsonantCount);




        System.out.println("Do you want to enter another string? ");
        String loopAgain = input.next();
        if (loopAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
            break;
        }

    }
}

}
```

How do I reset the VowelCount and ConsonantCount after looping again? Currently, it's adding onto the counter without resetting to zero. Please help. My instructor wants me to break out of the loop if I say N or loop again if its any other character

Comment: by setting counter = 0 ?

Comment: any reason you initialise the values **before** starting the main loop? Notice those variables are never used outside the main loop

Comment: Hello ecan99simmons. Welcome to StackOverflow. While there is a very simple answer to this question, I (and probably others) might be reluctant to help, because this is a very basic question, to which you can find an answer in many tutorials or online references. Please don't take this negatively, it's just that helping you here seems like doing your homework for you, which is detrimental to your progress in learning how to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to reset it after you print?
All you need to do is assign it like any other variable

```
System.out.println("The number of vowels is: " + VowelCount);
System.out.println("The number of consonants is: " + ConsonantCount);
ConsonantCount = 0;
VowelCount = 0;
```

Another route you could take would be to declare your variables at the beginning of the while loop. This way, every time the while loop runs, it re-initializes the variables to zero, so you don't have to even reset it.

```
while (true) {
    int ConsonantCount = 0;
    int VowelCount = 0;
    ....
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the fact that you want reputation - but the quick answers to questions like this just encourage more questions of this quality. What are the chances someone else is going to have this specific problem?

Comment: @sleepToken Well by googling the name there are at least 5 duplicates in Java, so people definitely have this question multiple times, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331323/reset-counter-to-zero-in-java) for one of them.  Though this probably means the question should just be closed as a duplicate.